# Push local merge to GitHub and mark as merged

Tags: github

I performed a manual merge of two branches locally on my IDE. How can I commit the changes in a way that GitHub understands that a merge has taken place, i.e. mark the underlying pull request as merged?

Answer (score 2):

Say you have `master` and `develop` branch locally, and you have made some changes to `develop` and pushed it to the GitHub repo and then opened a PR from `develop` to `master`. Now if you merge changes of `develop` to `master` locally, then if you just push the `master` branch to GitHub, the open PR would automatically be marked as **Merged**.

Comment: Somehow today this exact process stopped working. Instead of showing PR as merged, it says PR has a merge conflict (despite commits being identical on both branches)... Either a bug in GitHub, or they changed this behavior,, which'd be really unfortunate

Answer (score 1):

Just push the target branch.

As long as you've merged to the correct branch and you haven't done anything to rewrite the commits, e.g. rebasing or squashing, the pull request will be updated automatically.